# клавиша tab в блоке ввода текста и tab и shift + tab на выделенной области

Tags: предложение, блок-кода

Может быть уже стоит добавить возможность печатать <kbd>tab</kbd>, нажимая клавишу <kbd>tab</kbd> внутри поля ввода (на текущий момент <kbd>tab</kbd> переключает на следующий интерактивный элемент страницы)?

А так же хотелось бы возможность использовать <kbd>tab</kbd> и <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>tab</kbd> на выделенной области для сдвига этой самой области.

Comment: есть скрипт для tampermonkey  https://web.archive.org/web/20170318173000/https://bitbucket.org/balpha/se-tab-edting/raw/tip/tab-editing.user.js    ...взято кажется отюсда  https://stackapps.com/q/3247/47223  .........но вообще да... давно пора ввести подобное.......... но предлагать надо не тут..... разрабы стака тут не сидят

Comment: https://github.com/SpectricSO/stack-scripts/tree/main/scripts/Tab4SE

Answer (score 2):

Это такое поведение браузера во всех полях ввода, во всём интернете, а не выдумка разработчиков сайта. Делать на сайте поведение отличное от "везде" не вижу особого смысла.

<kbd>tab</kbd> в браузере предназначен для навигации по фокусируемым с клавиатуры элементам. Отбирать у пользователей такую возможность не стоит.

Comment: Да, я думал над этим, однако можно было бы сделать что то типо shift+tab и ctrl+tab для уменьшения и увеличения табуляции

Comment: Или же перенести перенос на следующий элемент на ctrl+tab.

Comment: "Отбирать у пользователей такую возможность не стоит" — мне лично еще не разу не приходилось табом переключаться на другие поля, а вот вбивать четыре (а то и все двенадцать) пробелов по десять раз, когда набираешь код на питоне — постоянно. Да и на что там переключаться? Работа над отдельно заголовком и метками вопроса занимает менее пяти процентов времени работы с вопросом. В основном тексте вопроса _гораздо_ чаще нужно нажимать таб.